# Sortable column (by numbers) in admin users

Tags: functions, wp-admin, dashboard

So I have this code in my function PHP:

Add column

```
    /*
     * Add column to admin > users
     */

function yoursite_manage_users_columns( $columns ) {

    // $columns is a key/value array of column slugs and names
    $columns[ 'custom_field' ] = 'Coins';

    return $columns;
}
```

Retrieve data

```
    /*
     * Retrieving data to created column
     */

add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'yoursite_manage_users_columns', 10, 1 );

function yoursite_manage_users_custom_column( $output, $column_key, $user_id ) {

    switch ( $column_key ) {
        case 'custom_field':
            $value = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'usercoins', true );

            return $value;
            break;
        default: break;
    }

    // if no column slug found, return default output value
    return $output;
}

add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'yoursite_manage_users_custom_column', 10, 3 );
```

Make sortable

```
/*
 * Make our "Coins" column sortable
 */
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'yoursite_manage_users_custom_column_sortable' );
 
function yoursite_manage_users_custom_column_sortable( $columns ) {
    return wp_parse_args( array( 'custom_field' => 'usercoins' ), $columns );
}
```

The above code return data (0 to 1000..)

Everything works, except for sorting.

For some reason it sorts by username.

So if I click on sort, it will sort by username alphabet ascending order.
If I click again, it will sort by username alphabet descending order.

I need to sort by number count.

Is there something that I'm missing.

Desperately need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something that I'm missing

Yes, you need to actually add the function which will do the sorting based on your `usercoins` "sort by" value (that you set in your `yoursite_manage_users_custom_column_sortable()` function).

So you would hook your function on [`users_list_table_query_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/users_list_table_query_args/), then change the args so that the users are being sorted by the `usercoins` meta value (which is a *number*, hence I used `'type' => 'NUMERIC'`), like so:

```php
add_filter( 'users_list_table_query_args', 'yoursite_users_list_table_query_args' );
function yoursite_users_list_table_query_args( $args ) {
    if ( is_admin() && 'usercoins' === $args['orderby'] ) {
        /* These also work, but to include users who do NOT have the usercoins meta,
         * you should instead use the meta_query arg below:
        $args['meta_key'] = 'usercoins';
        $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
         */

        $meta_query   = isset( $args['meta_query'] ) ? (array) $args['meta_query'] : [];
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'relation'      => 'OR',
            'has_usercoins' => array(
                'key'  => 'usercoins',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            ),
            'no_usercoins'  => array(
                'key'     => 'usercoins',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        );

        $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
        $args['orderby']    = 'has_usercoins';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/ for the full list of arguments you can set or change in the `$args` array above.

Comment: thanks Sally CJ, worked like a charm!